# Bash: Is there a way to restrict the exposure of bash variables to the scope they are declared in?

Tags: bash, shell-script

In the following script, a function (g) has the value of its local variable (i) overwritten by a function (f) it calls.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

f() {
    #local i # Let's assume whoever wrote this function f forgot,
             # to declare its variables as being local to it
    i=0
}

g() {
    local i # How to declare i as being only modifiable in the
            # scope of g, but not by functions g calls?
    for i in 1 2 3; do
        f # overwrites the value of i with 0
        echo "i: $i"
    done
}

g

# output:
# i: 0
# i: 0
# i: 0
```

Is there a way to restrict the exposure of bash variables to the scope they are declared in?

Is there a way, to make variables function-local by default, if someone does not declare them as being global explicitely (e.g. with declare -g)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to run the troublesome code in a subshell:

```bash
g() {
    local i 
    for i in 1 2 3; do
        (f)           # <<
        echo "i: $i"
    done
}
```

```
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
```

Variables are global unless they are declared local. There's no avoiding that.

---

Oh, I forgot a very important aspect of `local` that is directly affecting this scenario: a "local" variable declared in `g` is read-write-able in `g` **and in any function called from `g`** (to any depth).

- variable `i` in `f` is in the local scope of `g`.

From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-local) (my emphasis):

> `local` can only be used within a function; it makes the variable name have a visible scope restricted to that function **and its children**.

---

quite tangentially, Perl has this same "problem" with its `local` command that was solved by a new `my` command:

```bash
$ perl -e '
  sub f { $i = 10; }
  sub g { local $i = 5; f; print "$i\n"; }
  # ......^^^^^
  g
  '
10

$ perl -e '
  sub f { $i = 10; }
  sub g { my $i = 5; f; print "$i\n"; }
  # ......^^
  g
  '
5
```

Comment: Well, i is declared local in g, but I get what you mean. I think this is a good solution, although one does not want to invoke a subshell in some cases.

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: Good to know this about Perl! I bet this will save me some headaches in the future :) If only Bash had such a 'my' specifier too.